# Mocking dependencies of a class which uses static factory

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, factory

For unit testing, how do I mock dependencies of a class which uses factories.

For example, if I have the following class:

```
public class SignalProcessor
{
  ISignalFilter signalFilter;

  public SignalProcessor()
  {
     this.signalFilter = SignalFilterFactory.GetInstance();
  }
}
```

Now in the unit test for SignalProcessor, I want to mock out ISignalFilter, i.e. use a test version of ISignalFilter. If I were using Dependency Injection instead of Factory, then I could have passed in a TestSignalFilter to the SignalProcessor constructor. But how can I mock ISignalFilter in factory case?

Comment: You should consider using a DI framework like Castle or Unity (if you're not already using one). These frameworks provide a facility to externalize factories to either an XML or a class (which itself can be unit-tested). Then you could have just have a single constructor "public SignalProcessor(ISignalFilter filter)".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inject the dependency:

```
public class SignalProcessor
{
  ISignalFilter signalFilter;

  public SignalProcessor() : this(SignalFilterFactory.GetInstance()) {}

  public SignalProcessor(ISignalFilter filter)
  {
     this.signalFilter = filter;
  }
}
```

Comment: interesting, so you are adding a new public constructor, which allows dependency injection, just for unit testing purposes. Not necessarily a bad thing, but any other ideas?

Comment: Sure, lots of other ideas.  This is the best one by far though.  Most other ideas are a variation of "create state somewhere then exploit it for testing purposes", which paves the road to hell.

Comment: I would even get rid of the default constructor. Just offer the version that has a ISignalFilter parameter. Then the signalProcessor class has no dependancy on the SignalFilterFactory. It does not care how the ISignalFilter is created - that is the responsibility of the caller.

Comment: Agreed @GarethOwen.  If we're headed down that road, I would not use a static factory either.